# Mouseover and mouseout javascript is not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my current code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Imagemap</title>
<script>
    function swapImageIn(id){
    document.getElementById(id).src='\\C:\Users\idb\Desktop\Websitefinal\usa.png';
    }
    function swapImageOut(id){
    document.getElementById(id).src='\\C:\Users\idb\Desktop\Websitefinal\worldmap_load.png';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
   <img src="\\C:\Users\idb\Desktop\Websitefinal\worldmap_load.png" id="main" alt="" usemap="#worldmap_load" style="border-style:none" />
</div>

<div>
<map id="worldmap_load" name="worldmap_load">
<area shape="poly" alt="USA" coords="77,49,109,23,86,11,0,34,0,78" nohref="nohref" title="USA" onMouseOver="swapImageIn('main')" onmouseout="swapImageOut('main')" />
</map>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the mouseover event and mouseout event to work. They do not currently work. Any suggestions?

Edit-
When the area of a map is moused over I want an image to change. The event "onMouseOver" is never reached, however.

Comment: You need to escape backslash use \\

Comment: Define "is not working". Is there an error message? Is your `swapImageIn` method being called at all? (You can test it by adding an `alert()` call).

Comment: give a better explanation what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ah sorry - no the method is not being called at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works here. I reckon it's the filepath that's a problem. (Use forward slashes)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function swapImageIn(tgtIdStr)
{
    document.getElementById(tgtIdStr).src = "C:/xampp/htdocs/enhzflep/img/img1.png";
}
function swapImageOut(tgtIdStr)
{
    document.getElementById(tgtIdStr).src = "C:/xampp/htdocs/enhzflep/img/img2.png";
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       <img src="file.png" width='200' height='200' id="main" alt="" usemap="#worldmap_load" style="border-style:none" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <map id="worldmap_load" name="worldmap_load">
        <area shape="poly" alt="USA" coords="77,49,109,23,86,11,0,34,0,78" title="USA" onmouseover="swapImageIn('main')" onmouseout="swapImageOut('main')" />
        </map>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
function swapImageIn(id){
    return function() {
    document.getElementById(id).src='\\C:\Users\idb\Desktop\Websitefinal\usa.png';
    }
}
function swapImageOut(id){
    return function() {
    document.getElementById(id).src='\\C:\Users\idb\Desktop\Websitefinal\worldmap_load.png';
    }
}
```

and `onmouseout` should be `onMouseOut`

Comment: I suggest you use FireBug, put a breakpoint inside the function and see what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<script>
    function swapImageIn(id){
    document.getElementById(id).src='C:/Users/idb/Desktop/Websitefinal/usa.png';
    }
    function swapImageOut(id){
    document.getElementById(id).src='C:/Users/idb/Desktop/Websitefinal/worldmap_load.png';
    }
</script>
```

use this new one.

regards

Comment: try forward slashes, you're code working fine to me. however i changed address. so change your addresses in proper way.